# Extract a single file from a tar file to another directory

Tags: unix, tar, ksh

I have a tar file and I need to extract a single file from it and put it to another directory.

I tried this but it gives an error message. It did extract the file but not to the directory that I want but it extracted the file to the same directory.

```
tar xvf tarfile.tar -C /home/myDir filename_tobe_extracted
```

The error is:

```
x filename_tobe_extracted, 4046 bytes, 8 media blocks.
File -C not present in the archive.
File /home/myDir not present in the archive.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your command works as expected in my tests, both in GNU tar (1.26) and BSD tar (2.6.2).

The format of your output suggests you're using a different version from either of those.  Adding the output of `tar --version` to your question may be helpful.  In any case, your version of tar seems to be having problems parsing the command arguments, so I recommend splitting them up and flipping them around.  Maybe try:

```
tar -x -v -C /home/myDir -f tarfile.tar filename_tobe_extracted
```